# Google API error, Unauthorised client using the service account

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm getting the following error after that:

Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method." }

for  google admin settings we are following this link:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts

we are using restapi.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=client_secret.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('rwmp');
$client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setSubject('user@myconference.center');


$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
    $service = new Google_Service_Sheets( $client );

$spreadsheetId = '1WtuEXGm8oWxet6t9UcPU-mi7lgif1sqeTcmc9DO-_zs';
        $range = 'A:G';
        $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId,$range);
        $values = $response->getValues();
```

(a) we are using G-Suite "Basic Edition"; does that have any restriction?
(b) We are calling G-Suite APIs from PHP (7.0) environment; is there any known issue since the environment is still marked as '(Beta)'.
(c) Is there any sample/ tutorial which can give pointer to solve our problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the solution, we've to pick the scope from our admin configuration and use that.

ex:$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'));